# Loop finds value it doesn't have to

Tags: python, loops, recursion, tree

So, I made a code that goes through the dict and finds if the values are in the dict keys.

```
king_attack_moves = {(450, 750): [(750, 450)], (150, 450): [(450, 750)], (550, 50): [(150, 450), (50, 550)]}
king_attack_keys = [(450, 750), (150, 450), (550, 50)]

def standartization_for_king(current, king_keys, king_moves):
    if current in king_keys:
        for i in range(len(king_moves[current])):
            print(current,i,len(king_moves[current]))
            if king_moves[current][i] in king_attack_keys:
                current, king_moves = standartization_for_king(king_moves[current][i], king_keys,king_moves)
    return current, king_moves




current, king_attack_moves = standartization_for_king((550, 50), king_attack_keys, king_attack_moves)
```

For some reason, it throws me **IndexError: list index out of range** for
`if king_attack_moves[current][i] in king_attack_keys:`. As I figured out it is because at some point **i** became equal 1 at `{(450, 750): [(750, 450)]}` so it causes troubles because there is no value with index 1 in this list. I don't really understand the reason why i became 1. I beg for your help.

I use python 3.10.5 and pyCharm 2020.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.

Comment: I had to replace  current, king_moves = standartization_for_king(king_moves[current][i], king_keys,king_moves with  p_current, king_moves = standartization_for_king(king_moves[current][i], king_keys,king_moves

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `i` became 1, because the range you are looping through is range(0,2). Actually, `range(len(king_moves[current]))` is evaluating to 2 because current is (550, 50).

But your big deal isn't there : the main issue in your code is that you modify the value `current` while you are iterating with. Let's say you are hacking your own for loop correct operation. Try to choose other variable name, or use different looping mechanisms, like a while loop, whatever you are trying to do.

Moreover, if I may suggest some leads of improvement, you can simplify your code in many ways:

- Don't return `king_moves` from your recursive function. It seems you don't want it to be modified, and you already 'inject' it from the function call signature.
- For you data declaration, you can use `king_attack_keys = list(king_attack_moves.keys())`. It will make you avoid some desynchronization between values.